# android live streaming of tv

Tags: android, streaming, live

I am developing app in which I have to implement live tv streaming. I am trying in internet but I am not getting  good solutions . please help me to solve this..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android already supports many video codecs (such as H264) and a variety of streaming mechanisms (such as RTSP and plain HTTP).

The simplest streaming setup would involve using any off-the-shelf encoder/server to produce such a stream (such as H264 over RTSP) on a PC, and then point the Android web browser to that address, which will launch the built-in media player to play the stream.

This wouldn't even require you to write a single line of code!

Comment: Hi, can u please explain me this "The simplest streaming setup would involve using any off-the-shelf encoder/server to produce such a stream (such as H264 over RTSP) on a PC" in broader way.  please help me to achieve this. I am in urgent need of this.

Comment: I mean something *like* this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wowza_Media_Server (there are lots of alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

If still any existing problem is there, then you can use vlc media player plugin inside your application or you can call through intent if once the vlc media player is installed in your android phone

Intent i = new Intent("org.videolan.vlc.VLCApplication.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity"); i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("rtsp://10.0.0.179:8086/")); startActivity(i);